# Do we have to use system dependent file separator in java.io.File path?

Tags: java

Do we actually need to provide correct file separator in java.io.File path expression? In other words, does it make any difference to write `path + File.separator + fileName` instead of  `path + "/" + fileName` for any OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some people might say technically yes, but in practice since windows works with either \ or /, just use unix file separators and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I usually stick to File.seperator .

However I noticed that Java is smart enough to handle correctly "/" on any operating system.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably that you don't know in wich version of windows will be your application and for this reason I recommend you to use always System.getProperty(file.separator);

Comment: Can you please fixthe class name, "File" not "file".